# Mysql - Display all Count Rows Base on Month and Year

Tags: php, mysql

How to count records base on a specific Year and Month? Eg, that I want to make is as below,

```
|  Category | Total  |
|-----------|--------|
|  Cat 1    |  15    |
|  Cat 2    |  0     |
|  Cat 3    |  20    |
|  Cat 4    |  18    |
```

This is the query that I did,

```
SELECT kc.jenis_katCuti, count(pc.id) AS jum_cuti
FROM permohonan_cuti pc
RIGHT JOIN kat_cuti kc on kc.katCuti_id=pc.katCuti_id
WHERE YEAR(pc.tarikh_mula)=2017 AND MONTH(pc.tarikh_mula)=1
GROUP BY kc.jenis_katCuti
```

From the query, it will display only for the `Year` and `Month` that user choose. I want it to **display all the records and return 0** if there is no record for the particular month and year.

I also tried below but still with *no success*,

```
SELECT kc.jenis_katCuti, count(YEAR(pc.tarikh_mula)=2017 
AND MONTH(pc.tarikh_mula)=1) AS jum_cuti
FROM permohonan_cuti pc
RIGHT JOIN kat_cuti kc on kc.katCuti_id=pc.katCuti_id
GROUP BY kc.jenis_katCuti
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case when` in `count` like this:

```
SELECT 
    kc.jenis_katCuti,
    count(CASE WHEN YEAR(pc.tarikh_mula) = 2017 AND MONTH(pc.tarikh_mula) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS jum_cuti
FROM permohonan_cuti pc
RIGHT JOIN kat_cuti kc on kc.katCuti_id = pc.katCuti_id
GROUP BY kc.jenis_katCuti
```

cause `count` only excludes `null`, the expression `YEAR(pc.tarikh_mula) = 2017 AND MONTH(pc.tarikh_mula) = 1` will return 1 or 0, `count` will include both of them.

If you just use `YEAR(pc.tarikh_mula) = 2017 AND MONTH(pc.tarikh_mula) = 1`, try `sum`:

```
SELECT 
    kc.jenis_katCuti,
    sum(YEAR(pc.tarikh_mula) = 2017 AND MONTH(pc.tarikh_mula) = 1) AS jum_cuti
FROM permohonan_cuti pc
RIGHT JOIN kat_cuti kc on kc.katCuti_id = pc.katCuti_id
GROUP BY kc.jenis_katCuti
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Foward. Awesome! I'm a bit confuse of count and sum

Comment: @Foward, 1 final question. May I know how to get the total of jum_cuti? I `echo jum_cuti` but it return 0 or do I need to make another count query.

Comment: @Amran Google 'mysql rollup'.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Made it. Now I'm searching if I can have a title to replace the NULL on ROLLUP.